# How to configure RollUp (or Ionic Copy Script) to override files in assets directory on ionic build?

Tags: ionic2, rollup

How to configure Ionic App Scripts to update assets on each build?

I found: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-app-scripts#custom-config-files, which says add `clean` keyword. But it does not update `www/assets` on build.

We need to manually delete this each time. All my team is experiencing this and in gitter chat I found already 4 developers reporting this bug.

Answer (score 0):

After thorough investigation I reported this behaviour (assets not updated) as a bug:

https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-app-scripts/issues/236